# Tratchenberg Division Method

Tags: arithmetic

$ 743567 \div 256 =$?

I get the following method:

$ 7  4  3  5  6  7 \div 256 = 2$
__24,
  7, 23,

And since $23 \div 2 > 9$, I choose $23 \div 3$ to get:

$ 7  4  3  5  6  7 \div 256 = 27$
__24, 63
  7, 23, 52

Then since $52 \div 2 > 9$, I have to bump it up to $52 \div 6$, but how does that affect the other digits?

Thanks for you help.